# Install pandoc v2.X in AWS Lambda container images/Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pandoc, amazon-linux

I am trying to install pandoc into [AWS Lambda container image](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-lambda-provided). The image is based on Amazon Linux Base operating system, which itself is based on RHEL/CentOS 7.x (as stated in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/798427/what-linux-distribution-is-the-amazon-linux-ami-based-on)).

However, the pandoc rpm available in the Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) repository is v1.12.3 (https://pkgs.org/search/?q=pandoc). `yum install pandoc` will get and install pandoc v1.12.3, yet not desired pandoc version (at least v2.X).

**Is it possible to install v2 of pandoc inside AWS Lambda container image/Amazon Linux?**

---

##### Appendix: Unsuccessful direct install of `tar.gz` package

[Documentation of pandoc](https://pandoc.org/installing.html#linux) stated that it is possible to install tarball directly. However, pandoc is running at an outrageously slow speed using this approach.

I tried to install from tarball version of pandoc v2.x directly using the following commands.

```sh
wget https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/download/2.11.4/pandoc-2.11.4-linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar xvzf pandoc-2.11.4-linux-amd64.tar.gz --strip-components 1 -C /usr/local
rm -rf pandoc-2.11.4*
```

Although pandoc is installed, the running speed is outrageously slow. It takes > 10 secs to print the pandoc version. Converting a simple markdown file to HTML takes around 1 min.

```sh
sh-4.2# time pandoc -v
pandoc 2.11.4

real    0m15.941s
user    0m12.143s
sys 0m3.795s
sh-4.2#
```

As compared to the v1.x rpm package, which pandoc will immediately (< 0.5 sec) print the version as usual.

```sh
sh-4.2# time pandoc -v
pandoc 1.12.3.1

real    0m0.249s
user    0m0.122s
sys 0m0.052s
```

Comment: Why not install the latest portable linux package from <https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases>? This is statically linked.

Comment: @JohnMacFarlane I tried to install the tarball version. Although pandoc could be installed on the OS, it is running at a very slow speed (stated in the appendix) and cannot figure out the reason behind it.

Comment: Why were you trying to install version 2.11.4?  Can you try with 2.16.2, the latest?

Comment: Same result using pandoc 2.16.2. I tested with some other versions (2.9.2.1, 2.5) and the same problem exists.

Comment: Weird.  I'm sorry, it's a mystery to me too.  Let me know if you discover anything.

Comment: Sure, will keep you posted (I guess the problem relates to AWS rather than pandoc). Thanks for your help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I just ran in the same problem (to get `nbconvert` to work).

This worked for me:

```bash
sudo yum -y install epel-release
sudo yum -y install pandoc --enablerepo=epel
```

For sake of completeness (not sure if necessary for `pandoc`, but I needed it for `nbconvert`), I also installed `xetex`:

```bash
sudo yum -y install texlive-xetex texlive-fonts-recommended \
  texlive-plain-generic --enablerepo=epel
```